# How to reload external property files in spring boot without tomcat restart?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to read external property file in spring boot application. This process is currently working perfectly. As my requirement changed, I need to set some property on the go and that property should be reloaded automatically in application without manually restarting Tomcat. Currently I have two POJO for the property files and it gets initialized by spring. I want to initialize it manually while I call my rest service. I have created I tried with @Refreshscope but not working.

*AppController.java*

```
//initial code segments
public class AppController {

LocalProperties localProperties;

@PostMapping(value = "/getdata", produces = "application/json")
    public String getResponse(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestBody String request) {
       //Somthing like below method to initilize external properties
        loadExternalPropeteries();
        //use the property classes in business logic
}

    private void loadExternalPropeteries() {
        //Assuming the the object wil be created now
        localProperties=new LocalProperties();      
    }
}
```

Currently the POJO for property
*LocalProperties.java*

```
@PropertySource("file:${spring.config.location}/localConfig.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class LocalProperties {
    @Value("${server.url}")
    private String url;
}
```

Comment: Try autowiring`localProperties` in your controller instead, `@Autowired LocalProperties localProperties` and remove the method call in `getResponse()`

Comment: You also need to import Spring Boot Actuator in order to use `@RefreshScope` with Spring Cloud

Comment: I have tried ```@autowired``` and it works for one time loading of the properties when spring starts. Also tried integrating ```@RefreshScope``` but refresh dosen't happen.

Answer (score 1):

try to follow instruction from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties#reloading-cloud

Comment: Best to provide a summary and quote external link as source.